# google script: How to get rendered string value of a date cell?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The thing is that the date specified in the cell does not match the received in `gs`. It's hard to believe but just test it if you do not. I can hazard the guess that it might prove to not be the case for EST people, but I'm in Europe, so ... let's look into it:

Say, there is a cell with the date type in it:
`31.10.2022` with type `date`. Everything is well and good until I get the value of the cell from `gs`.
it returns:

```
Sun Oct 30 2022 17:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

At first glance it may appear that it is just the timezone ... but it's not. There're more than 4 hours which are missing. So `.getUTCDate()` or `.getUTCMonth()` do not do the trick, let alone the fact that `gs` does not accommodate with `.getUTCHours()` etc. (offtop: it's quite dazing since UTC hours or UTC minutes might have much wider appeal than UTC date or UTC month, but ... whatever, neither solve the problem)

Well, the more prominent thing is just to define something like `DATE_SHIFT` to correct each value taken from the `sheet` (no jokes).

```
  const DATE_SHIFT = (() => {
    const wrong_d = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getRange('A3').getValue();
    const target = Date.parse(`2022-10-31 ${wrong_d.getHours()}:${wrong_d.getMinutes()}:${wrong_d.getSeconds()}`);
    return target - wrong_d.getTime();
  })();
```

Seems quite bulky but it must work, shouldn't it?

It would not be `google` if it were so dead easy.

There are next problems which arise:

1. sometimes the hour is changed and it's not exactly 17, sometimes it is 16, for instance
2. sometimes the time returned is not EDT but EST
3. being run on some machines (though with synchronised time) the `.getMinutes()` and `.getSeconds()` results are not round for the same cell left intact, just from another machine (windows, btw, but does it really matter?)

I'm just lost. And what is the most surprising ... there is no such issues on the stackoverflow about it. I do not get it. What am I doing wrong?

Now I can come up with only one salvation from the described above hell: To get the `date` just as it is shown to the user, as a string. But I do not know how to make `google-sheet` do that service for me. To return `string` not `Date` from `.getValue()`. I'd wholeheartedly appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Try `getDisplayValue()`

Comment: @Cooper, really? You mean that?

Comment: @Cooper, Oh, really, there is such. I've tried to get it by the means of `getRichTextValue().getText()` but failed. You have saved the day!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It gets the value as a string.  Thats all

Comment: @Cooper, the exact thing which I was craving for. But somehow overlooked it in the `docs`.

Comment: Well there's a lot of new commands in the docs these days, so it is hard to keep up but that one's been there for a while.

Comment: I'm not a seasoned user of `google-sheet`. I was helping to a friend of mine. As a JS-dev, I preferred to do the trick with `gs` which is close to `js`, rather then something excel-like. So the `google-api` within `gs` was all new to me. The first experience with `gs` if it matters. Still and all, your answer was much appreciated.